# Error Generating Time Series Chart: No features contain non-null values of "system:time_start"

Tags: google-earth-engine, time-series

1. I'm getting the following error while generating the time series chart for Image Collection:

> ```
>        Error: No features contain non-null values of "system:time_start".
> ```

2. Here is the code that I have returned for generating the time series chart:

   ```
    // Study Area
    var Bhagwanpur = ee.FeatureCollection('projects/ee-omkarjadhav296/assets/Bhagwanpur_Merge');
    Map.addLayer(Bhagwanpur, {}, 'Bhagwanpur', false)
    Map.centerObject(Bhagwanpur, 10);


    // Load the Sentinel-1 ImageCollection, filter to Jun-Sep 2020 observations.
    var sentinel1 = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S1_GRD')
                      .filterDate('2021-05-01', '2022-06-05')
                      .filterBounds(Bhagwanpur)


    // Filter the Sentinel-1 collection by metadata properties.
    var vvVhIw = sentinel1
      // Filter to get images with VV and VH dual polarization.
      .filter(ee.Filter.listContains('transmitterReceiverPolarisation', 'VV'))
      .filter(ee.Filter.listContains('transmitterReceiverPolarisation', 'VH'))
      // Filter to get images collected in interferometric wide swath mode.
      .filter(ee.Filter.eq('instrumentMode', 'IW'));

    print(vvVhIw);

    var RVI = vvVhIw.map(function (image){

      var rvi = image.expression('sqrt(vv/(vv + vh))*(vv/vh)',
        {'vv': image.select('VV'),
         'vh': image.select('VH')
        }

        );

        return rvi;
      })


    var imageVisParam = {"opacity":1,
                         "bands":["VV"],
                         "min":0.01548,
                         "max":0.46221,
                         "gamma":1};

    Map.addLayer(RVI.first().clip(Bhagwanpur), imageVisParam, 'RVI', false);

              /*---------------------------------------------------------*/

    // Plotting of the graph:

    var chart =
        ui.Chart.image.seriesByRegion(
              RVI,
              Bhagwanpur,
              // .filter(ee.Filter.eq('Field_ID', 10)),
              ee.Reducer.mean(),
              'VV',
              10,
              'system:time_start'
            )
            .setSeriesNames(['RVI'])
            .setOptions({
              title: 'RVI',
              hAxis: {title: 'Date', titleTextStyle: {italic: false, bold: true}},
              vAxis: {
                title: 'RVI',
                titleTextStyle: {italic: false, bold: true}
              },
              lineWidth: 5,
              colors: ['#fc0303'],
              curveType: 'function'
            });

    print(chart);
   ```

Comment: We don't have access to your assets so we can't reproduce the error

Comment: can you please reproduce the result with your assets? as I'm working from the institutional accounts

Comment: No that is your responsibility. You can also create a dummy datasets that also shows your error or problem.

Comment: Ok, sir, I will pass the coordinates to you. Is it ok? because I tried solving the problem but was not able to resolve it

Comment: Coordinates- 'N' Lat- 29.87,  'W' Long- 77.766,  'S' Lat- 29.96,  'E' Long- 77.85

Comment: I used the point (76.8576, 29.5632) considered in my former answer and I could solve the problem. By the way, above coordinates are in a wrong order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With following correction it will be enough:

```
 var RVI = vvVhIw.map(function (image){
  
   var date = image.get('system:time_start');
  
   var rvi = image.expression('sqrt(vv/(vv + vh))*(vv/vh)',
     {'vv': image.select('VV'),
      'vh': image.select('VH')
     }

     );

     return rvi.set('system:time_start', date);

   });
```

I used [complete code](https://code.earthengine.google.com/797b951244f744cba6a267cd13032491) with point (76.8576, 29.5632) in your ROI. Change for your Bhagwanpur layer in corresponding asset.

After running complete code in GEE code editor, chart was printed without any problem.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, sir. It worked for me.